# Exact sequence properties

Tags: algebraic-topology, exact-sequence

If $0 \stackrel{\gamma}\to C_n \stackrel{d_n}\to C_{n-1} \to \dots C_0\to 0$ is exact, then it induces the short exact sequence

$$0 \to \ker d_n \to C_n \to \text{img}d_{n} \to 0?$$

This is part of the Euler Characteristic proof. I stared at this for a while, but it isn't too clear to me. Is this the correct justification?

Since $\ker d_n \hookrightarrow{} C_n$ in a one-to-one fashion, the boundary map $C_n \stackrel{d_{n}}\to\text{img}d_{n} \subset C_{n-1}$ maps back into $C_{n-1}$ (actually it is $0$ from $d^2 = 0$?). So $\ker d_n \subset \text{img}d_{n}$. Also $\text{img}d_{n}  \approx C_n/\ker d_n = C_n/\text{img}\gamma_{n} = C_n/\{0\} \approx C_n$. Actually I am not sure how to find the other inclusion.

Comment: Your justification is not clear at all, and statements like "$\ker d_n \subset \text{img}d_{n}$" make no sense (the two sides aren't even subsets of the same module). Try to be less handwavy (what does "maps back" mean?) and more formal, even at the cost of greater length.

Comment: @darijgrinberg $\iota(\ker d_n) \subset C_n$, then $d_n(\iota(\ker d_n)) \subset img d_n \subset C_{n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\stackrel f\to B$ is a homomorphism, then 
$$0\to \ker f\stackrel \subseteq\to A \stackrel f\to\operatorname{img}f \to 0$$
is a short exact sequence. Clearly, the incusion is injective and $f$ is surjective (to $\operatorname{img}f$). Finally the kernel of $f$ is ... $\ker f$, as desired.